# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SVGImage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;

namespace ModernMirror.App
{

    public class IconPropertView : PropertyView
    {
        SVGImage icon;

        public Sprite[] icons;

        void Awake()
        {
            icon = GetComponent<SVGImage>();
        }

        override public void SetProp(object id)
        {
            int i = 0;
            try
            {
                i = int.Parse((string)id);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Could not parse integer from property id " + id + e);
            }
            if (icons == null || i >= icons.Length)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Missing icons for IconProperty " + name);
                return;
            }
            icon.sprite = icons[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I am building unity project and got this error.
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SVGImage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hover on it, it will offer some possible fixes. If you have the package, it will say to add the namespace.

Comment: Do you have the `VectorGraphics` package installed in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
using Unity.VectorGraphics
```

per https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0/api/Unity.VectorGraphics.SVGImage.html

Comment: I have downgrade unity version and it is working now.

Comment: I have used it but getting error, i think it is version error

Answer (score 0):

Put your *.cs files to "Scripts" directory.